# Non Deterministic Results Using GPUs with Tensorflow and Tensorflow Serving . .. Why?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

We have an object detection model developed in Tensorflow (1.10 and 1.3) that uses a standard CNN and some extra layers.  We host the model in Tensorflow Serving 1.13.0 using a saved model format, on Nvidia Tesla V100 GPUs with Cuda 10 and CUDNN 7.4.x. (We use the Google containers images and/or dockerfiles for Tensorflow serving.)

We run unit tests to ensure that prediction results are what we expect.  These all work great on CPU.  But when we run them on the above GPU/CUDA/CUDNN configuration, we get differences in the prediction probabilities ranging from .001 to .0005.

Our goals are to understand:

- why this happens?
- is there anything we can do to prevent it?
- If there is something we can do to prevent it, does that entail some sort of trade off, such as performance?

We have tried the following experiments:

1. Multiple runs of the same model on tensorflow GPU using checkpoint with batchsize of 1

   - results identical
2. Multiple runs of the same model on GPU using checkpoint with various batchsizes

   - results off by .001
3. Multiple runs of the same model on CPU  using checkpoint with various batchsizes

   - results identical
4. Multiple runs of the same model on tensorflow serviing GPU using checkpoint with batchsize of 1

   - results identical
5. Comparing runs with checkpoint to runs with saved model on GPU

   - results off by .005
6. Compare runs with checkpoint to runs with savedmodel on CPU

   - results identical
7. Experimented with changing the batch_size and setting `TF_CUDNN_USE_AUTOTUNE=0` on GPU

   - reduces max difference from .001 to .0005
8. Experimented with adding `intra_op_parallelism_threads=1`, `inter_op_parallelism_threads=1` didn’t make any difference when used with `TF_CUDNN_USE_AUTOTUNE=0`

   - results no different than the above

IN SUMMARY: We have a few cases where the results of running inference on GPU  are different:

1. Using a checkpoint versus a saved model.
2. Batchsize = 1 versus various batch sizes
3. Setting `TF_CUDNN_USE_AUTOTUNE=0` reduces the difference when using various batch sizes

This happens with TF 1.10 AND 1.13.1

Again,  our goals are to understand:

1. Why this happens?
2. Is there anything we can do to prevent it?
3. If there is something we can do to prevent it, does that entail some sort of trade off, such as performance?

Comment: [This video](https://developer.nvidia.com/gtc/2019/video/S9911) may be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

I have some crazy nondeterministic stuff going on, that didn't occur in my laptop's GPU but happened in the server's GPUs.

Solution: Now I call `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` every time after a call to a cublas, cusolver, etc., function, and the nondeterministic issue dissapeared! :) It made me really crazy and angry but aparently because those libraries use stream, then you can end using the content of a device pointer before the results have been written completely by those libs' functions.